# run stop tomcat task if test task fails in gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I am working on a gradle project. I have written few tests for it.
In build.gradle, I have written three tasks for it: tomcatStart, tomcatEnd and test.
Inside test task, i am executing tomcatStart in doFirst and tomcatStop in doLast. 
It all works fine if there is no test failure. 
But if a test fails, the tomcat keeps on running.

I want to know if there is any way, i can stop tomcat even if test task fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `finalizebBy` property of the test task. It's well described in the official [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks). According to it:

> Finalizer tasks are useful in situations where the build creates a resource that has to be cleaned up regardless of the build failing or succeeding. An example of such a resource is a web container that is started before an integration test task and which should be always shut down, even if some of the tests fail.

And here is an example from the docs:

```
task taskX {
    doLast {
        println 'taskX'
        throw new RuntimeException()
    }
}
task taskY {
    doLast {
        println 'taskY'
    }
}

taskX.finalizedBy taskY
```

Comment: Thanks @Stanislav